# Turn off monitor in console with Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi

hi i am doing a function in delphi xe2 to turn off the monitor, I'm doing it in a console application, he had done in a graphical application without problem but when you step into the console application gives me these errors:

```
Undeclared identifier: 'Application'
Undeclared identifier: 'WM_SYSCOMMAND'
```

The source :

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,ShellApi,Windows;

function turn_off(): string;
const
  MONITOR_ON = -1;
  MONITOR_OFF = 2;
  MONITOR_STANDBY = 1;
begin
  SendMessage(Application.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF);
end;

begin
  try
    turn_off();
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

As I can do this in a console application?

Comment: Well, for starters, since it's a console application, `Application.Initialize` and `Application.Run` are never called. Also, you don't even have the necessary units in your `uses` clause. But that won't automatically fix your problem. The base of your problem is you need to pass an appropriate handle to send the message to. Unfortunately I can't test this in my environment because my IDE is via remote desktop, thus I don't want to risk unpredictable results without being in front of the IDE on the same machine :-) But `Application` resides in the `Forms` unit.

Comment: `Application` is declared in the `Forms` unit, which is not in your uses clause. Console applications don't have a message loop by default and don't have a window handle, so there's nothing to which you can `SendMessage`. Console applications don't have an `Application` to initialize or run.

Comment: then I can not do it in console?

Comment: Your question seems to be about the two compiler errors you're getting, which is why Jerry and I both mentioned them. You can *try* sending the message to the desktop window (using `GetDesktopWindow()` or `0` as the HWND to which you're sending the message). I'm not testing it, and therefore not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Undeclared identifier: 'Application'
>   Undeclared identifier: 'WM_SYSCOMMAND'

Undeclared identifier simply means that the named identifier has not been declared by this program. In this case you are missing two units from the `uses` clause. `Application` is declared in `Vcl.Forms` and `WM_SYSCOMMAND` is declared in `Winapi.Messages`. Add these units to deal with your compilation errors.

When you do this you'll discover that `Application.Handle` is `0`. So your code will fail to do anything. You'll need to send the message to a real window. If you are set on using the VCL, then I guess you could create a hidden form.

I do wonder whether you really need a console here. Perhaps you really want a GUI subsystem app that terminates as soon as it has done its work.

You don't need to use `ShellAPI` and your `turn_off` function does not return anything.

I also question using the VCL here. You will end up with an incredibly fat program to do such a trivial task. Personally I'd create a window with a call to `CreateWindow` and send the message there.